# Is it appropriate to email some new information to my recommendation-letter writers on Thanksgiving if the deadline is a few days later?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter, email

I just found out one of my grad school electronic applications is having problem with a third party letter service company. So I have to ask the letter  writers themselves to upload the recommendation letters. The deadline is the first day after returning from Thanksgiving so I am thinking to email them today (Thanksgiving) would that be inappropriate? (But if I do, of course I will say Happy Thanksgiving but sorry to bother you....etc)

Comment: Is the return day Friday (tomorrow) or Monday?

Comment: the returning day is Monday

Comment: A professor who does not want to take action on any email received on Thanksgiving day shouldn't be checking it, anyway...

Comment: Email is not real time communication.  You are not taking up anyone's Thanksgiving time by sending them an email on Thanksgiving.  I would send the email ASAP and let them decide when to deal with it.  The more time they have before the deadline, the better.

Answer (score 6):

Asking is always possible.
Expecting any response or action ... well, that, as they say, is another story.

Comment: As long as its not inappropriate, I want to at least tell them now rather than on Monday and say the deadline is "TODAY" - I think that may be worse, right?

Answer (score 1):

Today is the only potentially problematic day. You can mail them today or Friday without harm since either way they will have the whole weekend and Monday to respond. They are all inclined to be charitable towards you, so I don't think it matters whether you do it today or tomorrow.

Comment: I am sorry but is today ok? (you said today is potentially problematic but said I can mail today without harm so I am a bit confused)

Comment: If someone was the kind of person to get offended easily, then today has a slim potential for being bad, but all your recommenders are friendly to you, so I'm sure it'll be fine.